# show a "loader" in an image view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I know of a couple ways to do this (neither of which I like) - so I'm turning to the experts at SOF.

I want to use the `ProgressBar`. The catch is that I want to use this as the image/background for my `ImageView`. Is there a way to do this? I started trying this with `drawable` but I wasn't sure how to go about it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ViewSwitcher` to switch between the `ImageView` and a `ProgressBar`. You can set the `ProgressBar` as the first child, and when you are done loading the image, you can switch to the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameAnimation drawable as the source of the ImageView
or you can rotate it use TweenAnimation.

[Animation Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: Looks like I'll need to use that too, but how do I display a `ProgressBar` inside of a layout xml (drawable)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     ... >
     <ProgressBar
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/loading" />
 </LinearLayout>
```